# [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache]textureForKey:@”myImageName”]; return nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i have a lot of big images, when the device has not only my app in memory, my app make something strange:
i used

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"myImageName"];
```

to load all images.
i have some sprites that change their texture with:

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:@"myImageName"];
```

at the beginning of the game all goes well, all images are displayed.
but more i play more sprites become white.
sharedTextureCache automatically remove sprites on memory warning?
in RootViewController i have not changed anything and appears so:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
```

why can't i find the textures?

this is a cocos2d issue? or the right way to do this things is:

```
CCTexture2d *tex=[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:@"myImageName"];
if(!tex) [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"myImageName"];
[mysprite setTexture:tex]
```

thanks

Comment: That's a good question, I can't find much about using CCTexture myself. I have multiple texture spreadsheets and would like to use them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `purgeCachedData` in CCDirector.m:

```
-(void) purgeCachedData
{
    [CCLabelBMFont purgeCachedData];
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
}
```

and in a typical AppDelegate.m created from cocos2d template, there is:

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
}
```

As a result, `removeUnusedTextures` of `CCTextureCache` will be called, which eliminates all textures in the cache which is only retained by the cache itself.